# Does Transition have enough beats to unlock the GIFTED achievement?

Tags: bit-trip-beat

In my attempts to master Transition, I recently joined the 1 in 200 club of people with the ADEPT achievement: [get a multiplier of 50 in Normal difficulty](http://steamcommunity.com/id/badp/screenshot/596937916968366606). Hooray!

The next achievement would be GIFTED: get a multiplier of 100 in Normal difficulty. As seen in [this perfect Growth run](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUeosXGrjC8&feature=mfu_in_order&list=UL), this requires hitting **1,566 beats** with less than 8 misses. For comparison, Growth, the hardest level, has a grand total of 2,392 beats, and it features many groups of multiple beats that can be hit together, thus bloating that number.

Does Transition have enough beats to unlock GIFTED with it?

Answer (score 2):

One way I could determine this is by backwards engineering a perfect score. Luckily, perfect scores are so rare [Gaijin has a page just for this.](http://www.commandervideo.com/perfects.html) And [here's a result pertinent to our interests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXlKv.jpg), courtesy of Hannes Preiss: **68,506,715 points.**

Now, how does the scoring system in Bit.Trip.Beat work?

Scoring for each beat is determined by two factors:

- The increamental beat value

  - Start at 100 (in Normal mode, the only mode available on the Wii)
  - First ten beats hit are worth 100 each (8th beat in a row: 100 points).
  - Every beat in a row after the 10th are worth 100 (in Normal, 50 in Easy) plus the combo length (15th beat in a row: 115 points).
  - Reset after every mistake.
- The multiplier

  - The multiplier is always 1 in Hyper and Nether; 80 hits get you in Mega
  - For every 15 (8 in Easy) hits, the multiplier increments.

What we now need to do is use these rules to see how many beats in a row give that score. [According to my calculations*](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164414/SO/Bit%20Trip%20Beat%20Scoring.xlsx) (which might be off!), that's *around* **1,424 beats.** For now, the answer is no.

In other news, the top score for Descent is 128,089,655 — although you *can* miss beats in this and the Growth boss without losing the Perfect status. That's an excess of 1,750 beats, more than enough to get the achievement.

***** The one thing that spreadsheet doesn't count is challenges. Thus, lookups on the table aren't perfect; you can compare numbers with the perfect run video to see where they don't match and why; they're accurate up to the first stage.

Comment: [Steam leaderboards for Transition](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/BitTrip/leaderboards/19753). No idea what happened there... I guess somebody had fun with external tools ;)